# How can I disable the voicemail button on iPhone?

Tags: voicemail

I do not use the voicemail at all and from time to time I keep pressing the voicemail button by mistake.

I am looking for a solution to this problem. I observed many others are complaining about the same problem, even on Apple's forum but they closed the thread and keep it unresolved :p

Comment: I accidentaly push that button sometimes as well, and my mobile service provider (from whom I do not have a voicemail service) is always more than happy to charge me call fees.

Comment: Oh my gosh, your phone network charges you to pick up Voicemail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable voicemail button (not remove it) if you jailbreak and install "voicemailblock" from Cydia it will disable it. Works with SBSetting so you can enable and disable the button when you want.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that because the vast majority of people with iPhones do use voicemail, you're out of luck. Apple isn't known for providing settings or options that only a small percentage of users will want, especially if it's a setting that might prove confusing in the future.

Their UI designers likely weighed the number of users who don't want the button vs. the number of users who will be confused because their voicemail button is now missing and decided against the potential confusion. That certainly seems to be how they make most UI decisions.

Comment: This is an usability killer, Apple should be more realistic and allow people to disable the voicemail functionality. Too ofter I press it my mistake.

Comment: @sorin exactly and if someone doesn't have a flatrate every accidental touch of that button costs money. Apple is never user friendly, just simple.

Answer (score 1):

*5005*86*XXX#

hit the CALL button after typing that code into the dial screen

Use this to reset where the button dials

XXX  can be blank (*5005*86*#) and it will throw an error when this is pressed, or you can put another number in there to make a quick dial to someone else such as a phonecard.

Confirmed working on iOS 4.3

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work in iOS 6.0.1

Comment: I suspect any of these 'dial a number' fixes are carrier-specific.

Comment: I'm on Rogers Pay as you Go. Just tried this method (*5005*86*XXX#) on my iPhone 6 & it works.
Thanks

Comment: I tried the trick mentioned in this thread that says:
"*5005*86*XXX# hit the CALL button after typing that code into the dial screen" Confirmed to work on iphone 4S with iOS 9.3.5, unlocked (not jail-broken).

Comment: @sw.smayer97 I have an iPhone 4S with iOS 9.3.6 and it didn't work. I guess it's carrier specific

Answer (score 0):

You can use NoVoiceMail available on Cydia. Works with iOS 6, too.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to my service provider (DIGI Malaysia) about the issue. They can not help saying its iPhone's domain. The provider is happily making money @ 3 cents (USD) per hit or per mistake